# Test ethernet port for data loss

Tags: ethernet

We are trying to test the ethernet phy on our linux box for data loss.

As of now we just establish a tftp connection to a server to upload and download a file. Whenever a mismatch occurs, it is reported as failure. This is not a very nice test, as any mismatch might have been caused by the network itself and not a phy problem.

Can you suggest a way to test the ethernet phy in a better way for data loss?

Thanks...

Comment: Unplug the ethernet cable, plug into another pc, compare the two results.

Comment: If the box has 2 ports you could back-to-back them.  Sender on 1, receiver on another. Either that, or use a crossover cable between it and a different pc and put sender on 1 system, receiver on another?

Comment: @FreudianSlip I cannot do it with a system as I am testing multiple such boxes at the same time. Is it possible to do a loop back and test it? Would it include the ethernet phy?